# why String.class == "test".class

Tags: java, class

Anyone have any idea, why the `==`  sign works on `.class` comparison?

Besides, the javadoc for `getClass()` method as

> Returns the runtime class of this
>   Object. **The returned Class object is
>   the object that is locked by static
>   synchronized methods of the
>   represented class.**

The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass()` is called. For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:

```
Number n = 0; 
Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();
```

What does the "object locked by static synchronized methods"  means?

Answer (score 7):

`==` does identity comparison, and there's (normally) only one copy of each class. "object locked by static synchronized methods" means just what it says; it's the object that methods declared static and synchronized will attempt to lock.

Comment: I am thinking maybe there is some static variable, and is what the getClass() returns. That's why objectA.getClass() == objectB.getClass(). since it's the same static object (Class object) of their class.<br/> Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think Arams' answer is right.Returns the runtime class of this Object. The returned Class object is the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the represented class.